# Definition of local compactness

Tags: general-topology

By Munkres,

A space $X$ is said to be $locally$ $compact$ $at$ $x$ if there is some compact subspace $C$ of $X$ that contains a neighborhood of $x$.

Does this mean that every open neighborhood of $x$ has a compact set which contains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example the set $X$ itself is an open neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: And so what if $X$ is compact itself...?

Answer (score 1):

No. $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact, $U = \mathbb{R}$ is an open neighborhood of $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ that isn't contained in a compact set.